# TeleBot name error

Tags: python, telebot

Решил написать бота на telebot, прочитал пару статей.

Вот ошибка:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'message_handler'`

Код:

````
from telebot import types

bot ="токен"

@bot.message_handler()
def get_text_messages(message):
  if message.text == "/start":
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"123")
  else:
    bot.send_message("Подождите...")
bot.infinity_poling()```
````

Comment: в документации же есть пример...да и в статье наверняка тоже были примеры простейшего эхо-бота

Comment: не было примеров эхо бота(

Answer (score 4):

Обратите внимание на то, что *bot* должен иметь тип `telebot.TeleBot`, а не `str`. Ошибку можно исправить вызовом конструктора `TeleBot`:

```
from telebot import types, TeleBot

bot = TeleBot("токен")
```